# Closing a particular child window when parent window user logs out

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, window.open

I have a website, in which clicking a button will open user in child window.

```
 var childWindow=window.open('<?=$this->config->item('base_url').'after_login/portfolio' ?>', 'bypassed_user_window','height=' + screen.height + ',width=' + screen.width + ',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes');
```

Now, I want to close this child window when the parent window user logs out.
I am using Codeigniter.
If i give `<script>childWindow.close();</script>` in my controller, it gives undefined `childWindow` which is expected only. SO whats the way to close the window now. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The `childWindow` is indeed `undefined`. So, to achieve what you are trying to do, you need a reference to this window object. You might try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var childWindow = window.open('', 'bypassed_user_window');

    if (childWindow !== null) {
        childWindow.close();
    }
</script>
```

First of all, I'm not 100% sure if this will work in every browser, but if you specify the same name as before you should get the same window. If you get back the same reference to this object depends on the domains/ports used in the original window and the opened windowed. If closing this windows doesn't work, you can send this window to another URL in which you close the window itself. For more information, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open (and take a look at the Same origin policy mentioned on this page, to check if you can do what you would like to do).